# Wrapping managed with unmanaged interface

Tags: c++, clr, managed-c++

I have an unmanaged library exposing some interfaces. Users can implement interfaces and stick them into the library with their custom implementation.

I would like to supply a managed wrapper for this library.
Wrapping an unmanaged interface with a managed one is easy. But in my case I would like to support user implementations of various interfaces which means I need to take a managed implementation of an interface and wrap it using its unmanaged counterpart before I send it into the depths of the unmanaged part of the library.

I tried something like:

```
class UnmanagedWrapper {
DoSomething() {m_clr.DoSomething();}
IManaged^ m_clr;
}
```

But I cannot have managed members within an unmanaged class, the compiler rightfully claimed.

Can I do anything elgant here?

Comment: Not enough context.  Use gcroot<> or Marshal::GetFunctionPointerForDelegate().

Answer (score 0):

Here is some related information for work arounds when one library is unmanaged and a managed language uses those libraries.

The context of this information is a way to use GoogleTest in Visual Studio:

[Getting started with Google C++ Testing Framework](http://code.google.com/p/googletest/wiki/V1_6_Primer#Important_note_for_Visual_C++_users)

> Important note for Visual C++ users If you put your tests into a
>   library and your main() function is in a different library or in your
>   .exe file, those tests will not run. The reason is a bug in Visual
>   C++. When you define your tests, Google Test creates certain static
>   objects to register them. These objects are not referenced from
>   elsewhere but their constructors are still supposed to run. When
>   Visual C++ linker sees that nothing in the library is referenced from
>   other places it throws the library out. You have to reference your
>   library with tests from your main program to keep the linker from
>   discarding it. Here is how to do it. Somewhere in your library code
>   declare a function:
>
> `__declspec (dllexport) int PullInMyLibrary() { return 0; }`
>
> If you put your tests in a static library (not DLL) then __declspec(dllexport) is
>
> not required. Now, in your main program, write a code that invokes
>   that function:
>
> ```
>    int PullInMyLibrary(); 
>    static int dummy = PullInMyLibrary();
> ```
>
> This will
>   keep your tests referenced and will make them register themselves at
>   startup.
>
> In addition, if you define your tests in a static library, add
>   /OPT:NOREF to your main program linker options. If you use MSVC++ IDE,
>   go to your .exe project properties/Configuration
>   Properties/Linker/Optimization and set References setting to Keep
>   Unreferenced Data (/OPT:NOREF). This will keep Visual C++ linker from
>   discarding individual symbols generated by your tests from the final
>   executable.
>
> There is one more pitfall, though. If you use Google Test as a static
>   library (that's how it is defined in gtest.vcproj) your tests must
>   also reside in a static library. If you have to have them in a DLL,
>   you must change Google Test to build into a DLL as well. Otherwise
>   your tests will not run correctly or will not run at all. The general
>   conclusion here is: make your life easier - do not write your tests in
>   libraries!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe **[gcroot<>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/481fa11f.aspx)** is what you want:

```
class UnmanagedWrapper {
    DoSomething() {m_clr.DoSomething();}
    gcroot<IManaged^> m_clr;
}
```